# Write this integral as a power series

Tags: integration, power-series

I have the integral $$\int_h^{h+\epsilon\delta h}F\,{\rm d}z,$$ which I would like to represent as a power series of $\epsilon$. How might I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720828/endpoint-perturbation-theory/3720923#3720923

Comment: It does, thankyou.